# Opera won't install

Tags: command-line, deb, opera

I'm trying to run a .deb file with the latest version of opera in the terminal. I get the following output:

```
Failed to execute process './opera-stable_41.0.2353.46_amd64.deb'. Reason:
exec: Exec format error
The file './opera-stable_41.0.2353.46_amd64.deb' is marked as an executable but could not be run by the operating system.
```

Any help is much appriciated!